# Does turbulence increase with radius or decrease

Tags: fluid-dynamics

> IV lines must be regularly ‘flushed’ to avoid infection and line occlusion. More turbulent flushing better removes any particles attached to a catheter wall, which decreases chances of complications. Which of the following choices would be best suited to flush an IV line?

I was solving some questions on Khan academy and I couldn't figure out one of the questions and this was the answer

> A smaller lumen would increase the velocity of flow, increasing turbulence, therefore a low viscosity fluid with a small needle would be best suited

It says a needle with a small diameter will increase turbulence but higher Reynolds number indicates more turbulence

This confused me does turbulence more in tubed with bigger or smaller diameters?

Comment: The answer you cite is a bit hard to put into context when the situation described in the question isn't known.

Comment: @TBissinger I added it in

Comment: Thank you. I keep googling it and I don't find a good explanation: what's a lumen in this context? Just found that it may have something to do with the trachea. Is it some form of effective volume? Most translation pages just talk about the physics lumen as the measurement of light intensity. Sorry, not an English native speaker, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flow through a pipe/tube the Reynolds number $\text{Re}$ [is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number#Flow_in_a_pipe):

$$\text{Re}=\frac{WD}{\mu A}$$

where $A=\frac{\pi D^2}{4}$

so that:

$$\text{Re}=\frac{4W}{\pi \mu D}$$

It follows that, all other things being equal, smaller diameters lead to higher turbulence.

Answer (score 1):

The key parameter is the shear stress at the wall.  This determines whether an object will be swept off the wall.  For turbulent flow, the wall shear stress for a smooth tube is given by:  $$\tau_w=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2\frac{0.0791}{Re}$$At constant flow rate, this is proportional to diameter to the -3.75 power.  So under these circumstances, smaller diameter is better.

But for fixed pressure drop, $$\tau_w=\frac{D}{4L}\Delta p$$So, in this case, this is proportional to D to the +1 power.  So, larger diameter is better for this case.

Answer (score 1):

the flow in IV lines is never fast enough to become turbulent- it is always laminar. The faster the flow and the less viscous the fluid, the thinner becomes the boundary layer that is stuck to the inside of the IV line, and since it is that boundary layer which would contain contaminants, faster flow (still fully laminar!) will do a better job cleaning out the IV lines.